# Using a Word document in a work flow

Tags: workflow, word

We are trying to create a document workflow where a Word document/form would be completed by the user then emailed to the supervisor for approval. We'd also like to be able to add the email with the specific request in it. 
We  are very new to SharePoint. 
Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You should keep the document in a document library and send a link to the document via the email in the workflow. The workflow can then house the approval process for the document. Remember to quit thinking of this as a web site and email and more like SharePoint. I'm sure someone will post specifics.

Comment: By the way we are not using InfoPath to create this document, just Word.

Comment: You will find that all of the Office products integrate *fairly* well with SharePoint, especially the big three - Word, PP, and Excel. SP is all about collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SharePoint Designer, it's free and very easy to use.

Tell to workflow to check some field when the status is XXXX, so you can tell to send an email.

If you need to collect some feedback, SP Designer has collect feedback feature.